# Using triggers to implement referential integrity actions (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to implement some triggers for my tables

2 of the tables are `ORDERS` (has orders) and `ORDERS_ITEMS` (has items for each order), and I want to delete the `ORDER` when there are no more `ITEMS` in that `ORDER`.

I want my trigger to look something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_ORDER_WHEN_NO_ITEMS
INSTEAD OF DELETE 
ON ORDER
    DECLARE rowcount int;
BEGIN
    // First detemine if this is the last item in the ORDER
    SELECT Count(*) 
    INTO rowcount 
    FROM ORDER_ITEM 
    WHERE ORDER_ITEM.ItemNumber = old:ItemNumber;

    // Delete ITEM row
    DELETE ORDER_ITEM 
    WHERE ORDER_ITEM.ItemNumber = old:ItemNumber;

    // Last ITEM in ORDER delete the whole ORDER 
    IF (rowcount = 1) THEN
       DELETE ORDER 
       WHERE ORDER.OrderNumber = old:OrderNumber;
    END IF
END;
```

I'm not sure how to write this in SQL Server and I had the algorithm from a book but I couldn't run it on SQL Server.

Comment: I'm  just wondering why you are doing this on the DB? this sounds like a business rule, and would probably be easier and more manageable to handle in the code.

Comment: Please show the layout of your tables.  It is not clear to me why a table called `Order` would have a column called `ItemNumber`.  I would expect the foreign key relationship to be on a column such as `OrderId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a trigger for that. Use foriegn  key with [cascade delete.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx)

### Update

Sorry, I've jumped to the wrong conclution. If you want to delete the orders when there are no items connected to it, cascade delete will not help.
Use a triger for after delete on the order_item table and write this delete statement there: (**updated again**)

```
CREATE TRIGGER order_item_delete ON order_item
FOR DELETE
AS 

DELETE order
FROM order
INNER JOIN deleted ON (order.OrderNumber = deleted.OrderNumber) -- 1
LEFT JOIN order_Item ON(order.OrderNumber = order_item.OrderNumber) 
WHERE order_Item.ItemNumber IS NULL -- 2

GO
```

**Breakdown:**

1. The `inner join` with [`deleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) table will ensures you only delete records where the *OrderNumber* is the same as the deleted
   records from *order_item* table.
2. The `left join` with *order_item* table along with the `where` clause ensures you only delete records from *orders* table if they have no *order_item* records attached to them.

Comment: but I thought that Cascade delete will work ONLY  if you delete a parent then all children will be deleted too, but not the other way around?

Comment: @Zohar Peled From the question i get that he wants to delete Orders only when there is no more Order_Items that belong to that Order, not to Delete ALL Order_Items when he deletes the Order.

Comment: I really don't know where to put your code ? do I need IF condition? I mean in the Trigger itself?

Comment: See my edited answer. You don't need an if there. It might be a little slow uf you have many order items but i think for under 20,000-50,000 records you should be fine.

Comment: I got these errors Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 404
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 407
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I fixed the errors but when I tried to delete the last item from ORDER_ITEMS. It deleted more than one order.

Comment: Please uodate your question to include your cureent trigger. Also, check out gordon's answer.

Comment: I just change "exist" to "exists" but what happened that the trigger will delete the current order and all the rows under it for example if I deleted all the Items for Order number 5. ...Order 5 will be deleted along with 6,7 ,8 ......tell the end of the table.

Comment: See my edited answer (edited again...) I saw your comment to gordon's answer, if there are more tables connected with foreign keys to the orders table then you should make sure to either delete the records from them as well or delete only records that are not effected by the FK. In the problem continues, the best way to help us help you is to edit your question to contain the table's structure along with the FK constraint (preferably DDL).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks more like Oracle; SQL Server syntax is quite different.  For instance, there is no `new:` and `old:`.  Instead, there are tables, `inserted` and `deleted`.

If I understand correctly, you want to remove one item from the orders in the delete statement.  Then, if the last item has been removed, you want to delete the order itself.  I think the following does this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_orders_delete_one_item ON orders
    INSTEAD OF DELETE    
AS
begin
    with todelete  as (
        select oi.*, row_number() over (partition by OrderId order by ItemNumber desc) as seqnum
        from Order_Items oi
        where oi.OrderId in (select OrderId from deleted)
    )
    delete todelete
        where seqnum = 1;

    with todelete as (
          select o.*
          from orders o
          where o.OrderId in (select OrderId from deleted)
         )
    delete todelete
        where not exists (select 1
                          from order_item oi
                          where oi.OrderId = todelete.OrderId
                         )
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much the query didn't work because it says that ORDER has FK with CUSTOMER ( a table I didn't' mention) .

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer again, and I'm really sorry for not showing all my tables that was my bad .