# Best way to delete records in two tables having foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I created two tables like `marks` and `users`. I maintained foreign key relation between two tables, When I delete a row in `marks` table, I need to delete that particular user in user table based on `uid` that exists in both tables commonly.can anyone suggest me?

Comment: i tried like in one users table  with columns as sid,name,pwd,uid(PK),,similarily in marks table name all subject marks and uid(FK). if i tried to delete on row in marks based on that uid can i delete records in users table??

Comment: [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using triggers to implement referential integrity actions (SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086504/using-triggers-to-implement-referential-integrity-actions-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Use the ON DELETE CASCADE option if you want rows deleted in the child table when corresponding rows are deleted in the parent table.

> But your case is reverse from it.There is no way to do it reverse
>   automatically.
>
> You need to use delete trigger explicitly whenever record are delete
>   from child table.

BTW its not safe to do reverse as there might be many marks record for single user and if you delete any one of them then user is removed from user table.

I suggest to do it logically in sproc.

you can check in sproc that all record for user is deleted in mark table than remove user from user table.

Answer (score 2):

Well for your case, I will recommend using `on delete cascade`

More about it :
A foreign key with cascade delete means that if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted. This is called a cascade delete in SQL Server.

The syntax for creating a foreign key with cascade delete using a CREATE TABLE statement in SQL Server (Transact-SQL) is:

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
  column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
);
```

For more read [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

Comment: if i want to delete records from asp.net ,how can i implement that  in sql command ??

Comment: as far deleting is concerned, you can surely, but you have to be carefull, for example, you delete child record with uid 1, and then delete from parent table record  with uid 1, there can be still more child records having  uid as 1, and in this case it wont allow deletion

Comment: actually my main theme is if we delete records in marks table,then that person user pwd also wana delete,in that case only the deleted records person cant have permission to access.after that record deletion in both tables paralelly while login the user details not exist naa ? thats my situation.if anyone understand please rply,bcz i'm new to db that's y i'm not explaining clearly ..

Answer (score 0):

> In design just use on delete cascade

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
  column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
);
```

> Now when you delete parent . child will automatically deleted... you don't need to do any thing

check Link for detail
[On delete cascade](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

Answer (score 0):

As I don't like to `DELETE` any row from related tables, I suggest you this solution:

- Add a `status` field with default value of `1` to your table(s).
- Create a `VIEW` that shows only rows with `status <> 0` and use this `VIEW` to show your valid data.

> For parent-child or related tables just show rows with `status <> 0` for both of parent and child table like `parent.status * child.status <> 0`.
>
> [Optional & additional]<sup>*</sup> Create a `log` table or a `journal` for your database or your tables or just your important tables and store some actions like `Create`, `Edit\Modify`, `Delete`, `Undelete` and so on.
>
> With this solution you can:

- Support `Undo` and `Redo`.
- Support `Undelete` action!
- Be not worry about a child that has no parent.
- <sup>*</sup>Found old data, changes of data and many other information.

And many other benefits and you just store more data that it is not concern with a good RDBMS.

I use `DELETE` just for a table that is at the end child point and its data is not so important.